# indexOf method in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, indexof

So I have the line

`var a = document.cardform.cardnumber.value.toString;`

Then later:

```
else if (a.indexOf(' ')!=0 ||a.indexOf('+')!=0 || a.indexOf('-')!=0){
```

This checks that the user hasn't entered any unwanted +'s, -'s, or ' 's. The line seems to raise an error that looks like this:

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function.

I'm confused as to what it's telling me. Is it saying undefined isn't a function, or that 'a' is an incompatible data type? How do I fix this problem?

Comment: It's telling you that the function `String.prototype.toString` doesn't have an `indexOf` property.

Comment: `toString` is a function, but in any case, `value` is already a string.

Comment: Also, you probably want to check whether `indexOf` returns -1. It will return 0 if that character is the first character in the string (assuming you actually call `toString` first).

Comment: The built-in (on modern browsers) trim method on strings may be of more use. `var a = document.cardForm.cardnumber.value.trim();`

Answer (score 2):

You need to actually call the `toString()` function.

```
var a = document.cardform.cardnumber.value.toString();
```

Now, `a` is a string and has the method `.indexOf()`

Comment: Thank you! I feel stupid now, spent 30 minutes and all it was was a set of parentheses...

Comment: No problem, but as others noted, when getting the value of an input field you don't need to call the `toString()` function.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use `toString` method, then you need to call it, otherwise `a` is a function which doesn't have any `indexOf` method.

But you don't really need to do this, because `document.cardform.cardnumber.value` is already a string. Remember that form elements values are always strings.

Finally you can make a check much simpler with a basic regular expression:

```
else if (/[-+\s]/.test(a)) {
```